# Select box with 50+ word select

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a number of subtopics I would like to select using a select / dropdown box. The problem I have is that each subtopic is 30-50 words long. Does anyone know of any way that I can have multi-line selects within a select box? Right now I can show the select but because of my page size I have some data trucated.

I guess maybe jQuery has a solution but not sure as I'm not so familiar with jQuery

Comment: You want an option in a select to be on multiple lines?

Comment: yes that's what i need. There is so much content for each line of select that it won't fit on my page. Sometimes there's 100 words

Answer (score 2):

You better use [autocomplete](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/autocomplete)

To make the dropdown elements multi-line, just edit the css of `.ac_results li` making it taller (for instance, change `line-height`)

Comment: Good call. Very handy plugin.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But I need to let my users select from a list and let them see the selection choices one above the other.

Comment: But really I'm looking for functionalithy of a drop down where the uses can see an arrow to click and then a drop down list appears :-(

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a stock-HTML select element, perhaps consider using a div with *n* other divs inside it, each with their id as the ID of the subtopic (likely you'll need to prepend something if the Ids are numerical).  Show the div on click of whatever, select the subtopic on click of the individual subtopic div.  You can then style the divs how you want, allowing text to wrap, etc. This would also work well with an unordered list.

G

Answer (score 0):

I'd change my mind using something different than a select, rather using a div (or [dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/), or [accordion](http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion)) with [selectable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/selectable/) items in it using jQuery UI.